# A banner rotate3d loop with "on transitionend"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, logic

http://jsfiddle.net/CA4C5/

I am trying to make a 3d banner rotation.

First i had build 4 sides of it and then noticed that I probably only need 2:

/ Front side is visible and has Banner1 on it

/ it rotates down and makes Banner2 visible

/ once that is completed (on transitionend) it has to do 2 things simultaneously: 1. rotate back to the previous state in 0ms and change image 1 for 2 and 2 for 3 -> that works

/ upon reaching the last banner (var anzahlbanner) it should basically start over with number 1 (which seems tricky because when the last one slides into place and flips back it needs to show the last (f.e. 6 on the front) and banner1 on the hidden side.

But I dont even get so far because this function seems to fire twice, namely on the smooth transition and then on the flip back transition.

```
$("#eins").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){ ... });
```

You will see that when you activate line 31 in the javascript.

How can I get my counter go up the way I need it to?

Edit: It actually seems that the function is not called twice but one additional time for each turn: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 times etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I can simplify your javascript a little.

The only issue is that I changed your images for divs, with the image set in the background.

Now, your HTML is:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="eins">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="zwei">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

your CSS is

```
#container {
    width: 1269px;
    height: 294px;

}

#eins, #zwei {
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
}

 #eins {
    width: 1269px;
            height:294px;
            z-index:150;
            -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 147px;
            -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% 147px;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 147px;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 4s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
}
#zwei {
        background:red;
            width: 1269px;
            height:294px;
            z-index:70;
            -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 147px;
            -ms-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
            -ms-transition: 1s;
            -ms-transition-timing-function: ease;
            -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% 147px;
            -moz-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 147px;

            -webkit-animation: rotate 4s infinite;

}

#eins div, #zwei div {
    height:294px;

}

#eins div {
  -webkit-animation: imageseins 8s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
}
#zwei div {
  -webkit-animation: imageszwei 8s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -90deg);}
   50% {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);}
}


@-webkit-keyframes imageseins {
    0%, 49.99% {background-image:    url("http://jenseickhoff.de/testarea/2014/img/banner1.jpg")}
    50%, 100% {background-image:    url("http://jenseickhoff.de/testarea/2014/img/banner3.jpg")}
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageszwei {
    0%, 49.99% {background-image:    url("http://jenseickhoff.de/testarea/2014/img/banner2.jpg")}
    50%, 100% {background-image:    url("http://jenseickhoff.de/testarea/2014/img/banner4.jpg")}
}
```

And, as promised, your javascript is much easier (none)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/RPxJt/)

The trick is to set an animation on the images, that is changing the image when the div is not visible.